# How to retrieve webpart xml-definition programatically

Tags: web-part, javascript, client-object-model, xml, csom

I have a Custom Webpart deployed in the Site, to which I need to retrieve the XML definition programmatically using Client side object model, can anybody help?

EDIT: I used the following code.

```
    string strSiteUrl = SiteUrl_txt.Text;
        using (ClientContext cContext = new ClientContext(strSiteUrl))
        {
            //open Web
            Web oWeb = cContext.Web;
            cContext.Load(oWeb);
            File page = oWeb.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("MySiteUrl");
            LimitedWebPartManager limitedWebPartManager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
            cContext.Load(limitedWebPartManager, wps => wps.WebParts.Include(wp => wp.WebPart.Properties, wp => wp.WebPart.Title, wp => wp.WebPart.TitleUrl));
            cContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (WebPartDefinition wp in limitedWebPartManager.WebParts)
            {

                if (wp.WebPart.Properties.FieldValues.ContainsKey("UniqueValue"))
                {
                    //  Here I need to extract the XML definition, but not sure what should I 
                    //  add here so that I could get the entire XML definition, like the one 
                    //  we get when we export the webpart as XML in webpart gallery mannually.
                }
            }
```

Comment: I have updated the question with code I have tried.

Comment: This is similar to what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814829/how-to-read-webpart-content-using-sharepoint-client-om

Comment: @uberz91, Thanks. I did tried the same. I am getting SOAP exceptions. also there is no way we can export the XML programmatically using client side code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
try
        {
            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl)
            {
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                var page = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/sitecollection/site/Pages/Page.aspx");
                clientContext.Load(page);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                var webpartManager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
                clientContext.Load(webpartManager);

                var webparts = webpartManager.WebParts;
                clientContext.Load(webparts);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


                foreach (var webpart in webparts)
                {
                    clientContext.Load(webpart.WebPart.Properties);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    var propertyValue = webpart.WebPart.Properties.FieldValues;
                    if (propertyValue["Title"].Equals("My List Name"))
                    {
                        var xml = propertyValue["XmlDefinition"];
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                //do something
        }

    }
```